# Chrome Extension - store in background.js value from class tag for specific website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on making a chromecast extension for the Ballstreams.com website.  I'd like the extension to be able to read the direct_link value available on live-streams of the ballstreams.com site.  After I get the direct_link I should be able to use it as the currentMediaURL in the chromecast: [chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo()](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo) API call.

But, I'm having trouble scraping the direct_link from the current tab.  Here's where I'm at so far (I believe my problem is in the [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) call):

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "BallStreams Chromecast",
  "description": "Stream BallStreams to Chromecast",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": { "16": "ballstreams-16.png", "128": "ballstreams-128.png" },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": { "16": "ballstreams-16.png" }
  },
  "background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ] },
  "permissions" : [
    "tabs"]
}
```

background.js

```
var direct_link = "";
var activeTabId = null;

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  activeTabId = activeInfo.id;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    activeInfo.id, 
    {code: 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByClassName("direct_link").length > 0 ? document.getElementsByClassName("direct_link")[0].value : "N/A");'});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(match) {
  direct_link = match;
  if (direct_link != 'N/A') {
    chrome.pageAction.show(activeInfo.id)
  } else {
    chrome.pageAction.hide(activeInfo.id)    
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to add to your `permissions` section in the manifest the sites where you want `tabs.executeScript` to work.